# intermittent error - scheduling a job

Tags: scheduled-apex

During my deployments, sometimes one of my tests to the schedulers fail. Below are the error and the test code. The startScheduler method invokes System.schedule to schedule a job.
Can anyone please help me out?

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: A new job must have been created: Expected: 1, Actual: 0

```
@isTest 
static void whenStartSchedulerIsInvokedANewJobIsStarted() {
    List<AsyncApexJob> apexjobs = [select id, ApexClass.Name From AsyncApexJob where ApexClass.Name = :BatchMessageQueueProcessor.class.getName() ];
    integer nrJobsBefore = apexjobs.size();
    Test.startTest();
    MessageQueueUtils.StartScheduler();
    Test.stopTest();
    apexjobs = [select id, ApexClass.Name From AsyncApexJob where ApexClass.Name = :BatchMessageQueueProcessor.class.getName() ];
    integer nrJobsAfter = apexjobs.size();
    system.assertEquals(nrJobsBefore + 1, nrJobsAfter, 'A new job must have been created');
}
```

Below is the scheduling method

```
public static void StartScheduler() {
    if (startSchedulerRequested)
        return;
    startSchedulerRequested = true;
    List<CronTrigger> jobs = [select id, CronJobDetail.Name, State, NextFireTime From CronTrigger where CronJobDetail.Name like :schedulerPrefix + '%'];
    if (jobs.size() > 0 && jobs[0].state != CRON_JOB_STATUS_COMPLETED && jobs[0].state != CRON_JOB_STATUS_ERROR && jobs[0].state != CRON_JOB_STATUS_DELETED) {
        Set<String> activeJobStates = new Set<String> {ASYNC_APEX_JOB_STATUS_QUEUED, ASYNC_APEX_JOB_STATUS_PROCESSING, ASYNC_APEX_JOB_STATUS_PREPARING};
        List<AsyncApexJob> apexjobs = [select id, ApexClass.Name From AsyncApexJob where ApexClass.Name = :BatchMessageQueueProcessor.class.getName() and status in :activeJobStates];
        if (apexJobs.size() > 0) //the batch is running, exit
            return;
        if (DateTime.Now().AddSeconds(60) > jobs[0].NextFireTime) //if it is going to run soon, exit
            return;
    }
    //if the job exists it needs to be deleted
    if (jobs.size() > 0)
        System.abortJob(jobs[0].id);
    //we can query Messages to decide a targettime instead of one minute
    Datetime nextRun = DateTime.now().addSeconds(getSchedulerDelayInSeconds());
    try {
        System.schedule(schedulerPrefix + DateTime.now(), nextRun.second() + ' ' + nextRun.minute() + ' */1 ? * *', new SchedulerMessageQueue());
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

I'd just like to add that this almost never fails. So it is a hard one to catch (In fact it has only failed once)

Comment: Problem is that if you scheduled job name in test is same as in real life, it will fail, because scheduled job name should be uniq

Comment: The name of my schedulers are always System.schedule(schedulerPrefix + DateTime.now()... Si that is not the problem, thanks anyway

Comment: what's an error of failure?

Comment: The assertion fails, so when querying the AsyncApexJobs no new job is created

Comment: so, any chance to catch why scheduling of apex job failed? in debug logs or adjust MessageQueueUtils temporarily?

Comment: We'd have to see the schedule method. Presumably, you're either hitting the 100 limit, or since you're not using row locking, it's possible that a real job ended exactly during the middle of your test...

Comment: I've added the code and the info that so far it has failed only once. Which is one more time than what I'd like it to fail :D

Comment: empty catch. What if you place assert/dml/console log  there and see what is an exception?